# Formatting timestamps in twisted/python

Tags: python, twisted

I am running a twisted script to subscribe to stream using ApplicationRunner.  The output is something like:

```
2016-12-01T12:51:31-0500 n1  p1
2016-12-01T12:51:32-0500 n2  p2
```

What I want to do is reformat the timestamp to be

```
12:51:31
12:51:32
```

How can I do this?

Comment: can't you just use `[11:19]` slicing on all the file lines? no need for date parsing here.

Comment: Expanding on @Jean-FrançoisFabre, `for line in mylog: betterlog.write(line[11:19] + line[24:])`.

Comment: I just run ApplicationRunner(IP, Realm) and the timestamps come as part of twisted logs.  How can I modify twisted's settings to change timestamp format.